# How fix error in GoogleServices: Execution failed for task ':android:processDebugGoogleServices'?

Tags: android, libgdx

Please, help me.
I performed all the actions that gave me a site search and google but did not help to solve the problem

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':android:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
   Searched Location: 
  D:\Android Project\LibGdx\Rubl\android\src\debug\google-services.json
  D:\Android Project\LibGdx\Rubl\android\google-services.json
```

that remains to be done?
Gradle android

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
    compileSdkVersion 24
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "upwardteam.pavel.game"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 24
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.2.1'

}

// called every time gradle gets executed, takes the native dependencies of
// the natives configuration, and extracts them to the proper libs/ folders
// so they get packed with the APK.
task copyAndroidNatives() { 
    file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/arm64-v8a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86_64/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86/").mkdirs();

    configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
        def outputDir = null
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-arm64-v8a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/arm64-v8a")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")        
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86_64.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86_64")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
        if(outputDir != null) {
            copy {
                from zipTree(jar)
                into outputDir
                include "*.so"
            }
        }
    }
}

task run(type: Exec) {
    def path
    def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
    if (localProperties.exists()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
            properties.load(instr)
        }
        def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
        if (sdkDir) {
            path = sdkDir
        } else {
            path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
        }
    } else {
        path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
    }

    def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'upwardteam.pavel.game/upwardteam.pavel.game.AndroidLauncher'
}

// sets up the Android Eclipse project, using the old Ant based build.
eclipse {
    // need to specify Java source sets explicitly, SpringSource Gradle Eclipse plugin
    // ignores any nodes added in classpath.file.withXml
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs "src", 'gen'
        }
    }

    jdt {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.6
        targetCompatibility = 1.6
    }

    classpath {
        plusConfigurations += [ project.configurations.compile ]        
        containers 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK', 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES'       
    }

    project {
        name = appName + "-android"
        natures 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature'
        buildCommands.clear();
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder"
        buildCommand "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder"
    }
}

// sets up the Android Idea project, using the old Ant based build.
idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("src");
        scopes = [ COMPILE: [plus:[project.configurations.compile]]]        

        iml {
            withXml {
                def node = it.asNode()
                def builder = NodeBuilder.newInstance();
                builder.current = node;
                builder.component(name: "FacetManager") {
                    facet(type: "android", name: "Android") {
                        configuration {
                            option(name: "UPDATE_PROPERTY_FILES", value:"true")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Gradle Game

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
         classpath 'com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "rubl"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.3'
        roboVMVersion = '2.1.0'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
        aiVersion = '1.8.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-desktop:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-android:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:$box2DLightsVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.ashley:ashley:$ashleyVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-ai:$aiVersion"
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:$box2DLightsVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.ashley:ashley:$ashleyVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-ai:$aiVersion"
    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

**Execution failed for task ':android:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
>      Searched Location: 
>     D:\Android Project\LibGdx\Rubl\android\src\debug\google-services.json
>     D:\Android Project\LibGdx\Rubl\android\google-services.json
>   * Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.**

Comment: Please see the [Firebase troubleshooting topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/gradle/#troubleshooting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> File google-services.json is missing

Seems self-explanatory.

> ```
> Searched Location: 
>   D:\Android Project\LibGdx\Rubl\android\src\debug\google-services.json
>   D:\Android Project\LibGdx\Rubl\android\google-services.json
> ```

So, is there a `google-services.json` file in either of those two places? If not, you might need to go to your Google Developer console to download it.

Comment: tell me how to do it? I did not do this earlier

Comment: @upward In your new question, I see you have downloaded the file. Is there anything I need to add to this answer?